# Is there a way to save python scripts on arduino?

Tags: python, arduino

I'm using pyfirmata for load python scripts into arduino. But I don't know if there is a way to save that scripts on arduino.

I can load python scripts into Arduino using pyfirdata, but when I disconnect arduino board the program stops running. 
How can I save scripts into board to avoid this?

```
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
import time

board = Arduino("/dev/ttyACM0")

while True:
    board.digital[13].write(1)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    board.digital[13].write(0)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Your Python script has never been loaded nor executed on the Arduino: it runs on your PC and communicates with the Arduino. So, very short answer: no.

Comment: Arduino runs on C++, that is the default language the Arduino IDE compiler supports. You could, in theory, have a compiler created for the Atmel chip used on arduino that interprets Python code and coverts to the low-level code the chip expects, but it hasn't been done yet.